# Directory Does Not Create Using IIS Server

Tags: asp.net

[image]I am making a web application in asp.net there  i am making a directory in F drive through c# code. The code runs fine on my system and in IIS also but the problem is that when my partner using the same ip of my system the directory is not being created in his system i want who ever using the ip of my system the folder should be created and files should be save on that.[In the second image my partner is running the application the files get save on my directory not on his system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVUHW.png)

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: No i dont get the error message the code runs fine.

Comment: Please don't post your code [as an image](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332), but instead copy/paste any relevant code and use [code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). If we want to check your code we have to type it in all over again.

Comment: Okk sure but ii posted as an image to show only how i am making the directory thats why i posted the image

Comment: It doesn't matter: you need to provide the relevant code. Please review [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check your local directory it will be save there  not on the system using this ip address.